# Checking if object is undefined with variable does not work Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to access a key in an object, but of course before doing so I need to check if the object is defined first. This works if I reference the key with a string, but typescript yells if I reference it with a variable assigned with a string:

```js
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";

type State = {
  [id in string]?: {
      [fruit in Fruit]: {
          status: "ripe" | "rotten";
      };
  };
};

const state: State = {};

const id = "hello";

if (state[id]) {
  state[id].apple.status = "ripe";
  ^^^^^^^^^
  Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
}

if (state["hello"]) {
  // This is perfectly OK
  state["hello"].apple.status = "ripe";
}
```

Why is this?

See [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMiBuAWAChXRIoBlYbYaDAG9WUKAG0kAEyhJqUAM7A4s2gF0A-AC4owlqP3iAZohQy58ZMFXbdBuwt7AE87ZmWRiZN+WD9qmZj07AF9A0VDWCLYWAGNyakUHPghtHmT0HSjWOITUAAsIfHxyDMwCovIA1lYkQygACkVksXLi1QBKHREk-hbCtoA6XAIIAaaneVL3RkjqllqG8YgxMv7Kjq6gpZXW9aG8QjHHZymkD0DguaA)

Comment: Yes, these checks don't work in TS. You need to check a variable, e.g., `const myThing = state[id]; if (myThing) { myThing.apple.status = "ripe"; }`

Comment: Did My answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!` typescript ignores the fact that the value could be undefined which in your case is not

```
state[hello]!.apple.status = "ripe";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these instead of checking with just state['hello']

1. !!state['hello']
2. state['hello'] !== undefined

Comment: "*if (state['hello']) will always be true.*" not, if the property is missing, or the value is falsy then the `if` will not trigger.

Comment: `if (!!state['hello'])` is exactly the same as `if (state['hello'])`

Comment: Also, `state['hello'] !== undefined` (you have missing `d` at the end) will only work if the key is either missing or set to `undefined`, not if it's any other falsy value. Most notably `null`.